# Reorder of launching Systemd services

Tags: debian, ubuntu, systemd, sshd, systemd-unit

OS: Debian 11 Bullseye

Context:

- The [Zerotier](https://www.zerotier.com) application adds the `zerotier-one.service` system service and creates a virtual network interface (when it works).
- The `sshd` server default listens to all addresses `0.0.0.0`

**Until then, everything is fine with me**

Now I am introducing custom config in `/etc/ssh/sshd_config.d/my-sshd.conf` add `ListenAddress 192.168.10.10` that my `sshd` server accepts calls only at the Zerotier interface address.

Now I suspect that `sshd.service` starts before `zerotier-one.service` because after restarting the computer:

```
$ sudo systemctl status sshd.service
● ssh.service - OpenBSD Secure Shell server
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/ssh.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Thu 2023-09-14 17:21:27 CEST; 28s ago
       Docs: man:sshd(8)
             man:sshd_config(5)
    Process: 524 ExecStartPre=/usr/sbin/sshd -t (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
    Process: 551 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/sshd -D $SSHD_OPTS (code=exited, status=255/EXCEPTION)
   Main PID: 551 (code=exited, status=255/EXCEPTION)
        CPU: 21ms

systemd[1]: Starting OpenBSD Secure Shell server...
sshd[551]: error: Bind to port 22 on 192.168.10.10 failed: Cannot assign requested address.
sshd[551]: fatal: Cannot bind any address.
systemd[1]: ssh.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=255/EXCEPTION
systemd[1]: ssh.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
systemd[1]: Failed to start OpenBSD Secure Shell server
```

So I added the `After=` option to `/etc/systemd/system/ssh.service.d/override.conf` changing using the command `sudo systemctl edit sshd.service`:

```
[Unit]
After=network.target auditd.service
```

to:

```
[Unit]
After=network.target auditd.service network-online.target zerotier-one.service
```

It looks like this now:

```
$ sudo systemctl cat sshd.service
# /lib/systemd/system/ssh.service
[Unit]
Description=OpenBSD Secure Shell server
Documentation=man:sshd(8) man:sshd_config(5)
After=network.target auditd.service
ConditionPathExists=!/etc/ssh/sshd_not_to_be_run

[Service]
EnvironmentFile=-/etc/default/ssh
ExecStartPre=/usr/sbin/sshd -t
ExecStart=/usr/sbin/sshd -D $SSHD_OPTS
ExecReload=/usr/sbin/sshd -t
ExecReload=/bin/kill -HUP $MAINPID
KillMode=process
Restart=on-failure
RestartPreventExitStatus=255
Type=notify
RuntimeDirectory=sshd
RuntimeDirectoryMode=0755

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
Alias=sshd.service

# /etc/systemd/system/ssh.service.d/override.conf
[Unit]
After=network.target auditd.service network-online.target zerotier-one.service
```

**But after restarting the computer, the error still occurs**

When I do a `sudo systemctl restart sshd.service` now I get:

```
$ sudo systemctl status sshd.service
● ssh.service - OpenBSD Secure Shell server
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/ssh.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
    Drop-In: /etc/systemd/system/ssh.service.d
             └─override.conf
     Active: active (running) since Thu 2023-09-14 17:40:43 CEST; 2s ago
       Docs: man:sshd(8)
             man:sshd_config(5)
    Process: 3065 ExecStartPre=/usr/sbin/sshd -t (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
   Main PID: 3066 (sshd)
      Tasks: 1 (limit: 9423)
     Memory: 1.0M
        CPU: 21ms
     CGroup: /system.slice/ssh.service
             └─3066 sshd: /usr/sbin/sshd -D [listener] 0 of 10-100 startups

systemd[1]: Starting OpenBSD Secure Shell server...
sshd[3066]: Server listening on 192.168.10.10 port 22.
systemd[1]: Started OpenBSD Secure Shell server.
```

I have the impression that the `sshd.service` is still starting before `zerotier-one.service`

Is something missing or can it be checked differently?

Should I do something else in addition to adding `zerotier-one.service` to `After=`?

**EDIT (Information for other users):**

In addition to the solution proposed by @telkoM (for which I thank you), another trick solved the problem in my case:

Just add the directive `ExecStartPost=sleep 10` to `zerotier-one.service` or `ExecStartPre=sleep 10` to `sshd.service`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With your configuration, `sshd.service` will certainly start only after `zerotier-one.service` **starts**. But that is not enough. The `sshd.service` would need to wait until Zerotier has actually **connected successfully**, which can happen quite a bit later (in computer timescales, at least). And [the current `zerotier-one.service`](https://github.com/zerotier/ZeroTierOne/blob/dev/debian/zerotier-one.service) is not even trying to provide that information to `systemd`:

```
[Unit]
Description=ZeroTier One
After=network-online.target network.target
Wants=network-online.target

[Service]
ExecStart=/usr/sbin/zerotier-one
Restart=always
KillMode=process

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

You would probably have to create a `Type=oneshot` service (it could be called `zerotier-wait-online.service`) that would run a script that includes a loop that calls e.g. `zerotier-cli listnetworks` or just `ip addr show` and looks for the IP address 192.168.10.10. If it is not available, the script would sleep a few seconds and try again.

When the script would see the address has appeared, the script would exit - and that would tell `systemd` that any service configured to run `After=zerotier-wait-online.service` can now proceed. (Unlike the default `Type=simple` and several other service types, services of `Type=oneshot` are only considered "started" after their main `ExecStart` process has **successfully exited** - and that's exactly what you need.

Once you have that service working, you can change your `sshd.service` override to `After=zerotier-wait-online.service`, and then it should work as you wanted.

Note that you cannot simply require that `zerotier-wait-online.service` runs `Before=network-online.target`, because `zerotier-one.service` itself runs `After=network-online.target`. Trying to set up such a requirement would create an impossible situation.

---

The root of the problem is that the use of `ListenAddress` brings with it the requirement that the specified address must already be up when `sshd` starts.

If you need `sshd` to listen in the Zerotier IP address **only**, but don't specifically have to use `ListenAddress` to implement it, you could use alternative ways to implement the restriction.

In `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`, you could add a `Match` block like this, to deny access on any local IP address except the Zerotier one:

```
Match LocalAddress *,!192.168.10.10
    DenyUsers *
```

Or you could use `iptables` to drop/reject incoming connections if the destination address is anything except 192.168.10.10:

```
iptables -I INPUT 1 -p tcp --dport 22 \! -d 192.168.10.10/32 -j DROP
```

`DROP` makes blocked connection attempts hang until they time out; if you want the blocked connections to fail quickly, use a rule like this instead:

```
iptables -I INPUT 1 -p tcp --dport 22 \! -d 192.168.10.10/32 -j REJECT --reject-with tcp-reset
```

If you use `ufw` or some other firewall management system, there is probably a way to configure an equivalent rule to it.

Comment: I am not sure of this statement: _"The sshd.service would need to wait until Zerotier has actually connected successfully, which can happen quite a bit later"_ Since I did this test: I restored the original setting (I removed `ListenAddress 192.168.10.10` from the sshd configuration + I removed changes in `after=` in `sshd.service`) and restarted a computer without a physical network connection (i.e. zerotier also did not connect). The problem did not occur.

Comment: If you removed the ListenAddress directive, now `sshd` is listening on every IP address the system has, including any address added later. If that's fine for you, your problem is solved - but I thought you wanted `sshd` to listen in `192.168.10.10` **only**?

Comment: I only mean that `sshd` does not have to wait for the success of the internet connection via Zerotier. Does another solution come to your mind without creating an additional script?

Comment: There are alternate ways to achieve a similar restriction: see my edit above.

Comment: @telkoM Thanks for your help and see my edit above. Do you find using `sleep` elegant and safe?

Comment: It depends: if you know for sure that the service that needs to be waited for will always become ready in a fixed amount of time, it would be fine. Or if you can accept that the startup will usually work, but once in a great while (especially when you might have some other issue, like network connectivity problems) you might have to restart the service manually. I would not personally use `sleep` here, since the time you'd need to wait depend on factors external to the system, but that's just my preference.

Answer (score 1):

Any workaround will keep breaking because this is the incorrect layer to solve the problem. It is not on systemd or zerotier.. it is sshd that needs to allow setting the  *IP_FREEBIND* socket option to allow it to listen on addresses that are "not yet" or "ever" configured.
}

here is the patch to do it https://bugzilla.mindrot.org/attachment.cgi?id=2763 , it is correct but unfortunately openSSH developers did not accept it.

Comment: you can workaround using something like https://github.com/coreos/docs/blob/master/os/customizing-sshd.md in the section they provide socket activated sshd instructions